# Scrape urls from google's top page in python

Tags: python, scrape

I need to scrape google for the first 10-20 URL results for a keyword,  I found a lib called pygoogle but when I run it I get a syntax error: here is my code:

```
from pygoogle import pygoogle
g = pygoogle('quake 3 arena')
g.pages = 5
print '*Found %s results*'%(g.get_result_count())
g.get_urls()
```

Alright, it seems like pygoogle does not work anymore because Google deprecated the SOAP interface- does anyone know an alternative?

Comment: What is the syntax error do you get?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  That print syntax only works with the former.

Comment: If you need a alternative to html scraping because pypi does not work I used this tutorial. It is very fast and easy to get started:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: Note that `(g.get_result_count())` is not a 1-element tuple, it's just the single value wrapped in unnecessary and meaningless parentheses. Commas create tuples, not parentheses. (This happens to work anyway because of a quirk of `%`-formatting, but it's misleading—if you want to rely on that quirk, leave the parens off.)

Comment: I use Python 3 and I get "Invalid Syntax". But as TkTech said it seems like pygoogle does not work anymore.

Comment: OK, so you knew the parens were required and just forgot them. This seems like a simple typo that isn't worth having an answer. If you have a question about how to use Google's APIs, that's a completely separate question, and shouldn't be shoehorned into this one. (It may be a question that already has a dup, or that isn't appropriate for SO, or whatever, but it's definitely not part of this question.)

Comment: However, as a quick hint: Google now has a huge variety of different APIs. All of them can be accessed by relatively simple JSON REST calls that don't really need a custom library, but most of them do have an official custom library from Google anyway, usually with Python bindings. Do a bit of research on the API you want to use before asking about it, because a general "how do I call Google from Python" isn't going to have any useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're using the pygoogle from pypi, this package no longer works since Google deprecated the SOAP interface. Even if you fix the syntax error, this will not work.
2. *Always include the error message/stack trace* when you post a question!
3. You are probably using python 3, where print is a function (`print('Hello!')`) and not a keyword (`print 'Hello!'`) by default. <strike>Additionally, old style % formatting is deprecated, use `.format()` instead.</strike>

Comment: `%`-formatting is not deprecated. There was a bit of a war over it, and the final conclusion was that both have their place in different cases, `{}`-formatting should be encouraged as the go-to choice when you don't have a compelling reason otherwise, but neither should be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @abarnert, I wasn't aware that it had been settled.

Comment: I use python 3.4.2 so I forgot the parantheses for the print function. Since pygoogle does not work anymore does anyone know an alternative?